# Redirect logger messages from abstract child class that inherits Logger from parent

Tags: java, log4j2, spring-bean

I'm working on a Java project (not mine) that uses spring-beans among many other dependencies.
My goal is to redirect all the logger messages from several spring-beans classes to a file so that they're not visible in the console log. I went with the programmatic approach because that's what suits me more in this situation and after googling some Log4j solutions, found one that (almost) works for me:

```
public static void removeConsoleLogsByClassName(String fullClassName) {
    LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
    PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder()
            .withPattern("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{2} | [%t] | %-5level: - %m%n")
            .withConfiguration(config).build();
    Appender appender = FileAppender.createAppender(
             "some_location_goes_here/logfile.log",
            "false",
            "false", "fileAppender", "true", "false", "false", "8192", layout, null, "false", null, config);
    appender.start();
    config.addAppender(appender);
    AppenderRef ref = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef("fileAppender", null, null);
    AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[] { ref };
    org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger(false,
            org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.TRACE,
            fullClassName,
            "true", refs, null, config, null);
    loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, null, null);
    if ("false".equals(TestInfo.getEnableLog())) {
        loggerConfig.setLevel(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.OFF);
    }
    config.addLogger(fullClassName, loggerConfig);
    ctx.updateLoggers();
}
```

With this method, i can provide the Class name, and programmaticaly redirect the logger messages to a file, which is exactly what i need.
This works except for the (abstract) classes inside spring-beans that inherit LOGGER object from some parent class.

In my case, i'm trying to redirect log messages from AbstractBeanFactory to a file, but they still show up in console.
I presume it's because this class inherits the LOGGER object from DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry, but i'm not sure.

[Classes hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCS4s.png)

If anyone has any advice/solution for this, i would appreciate it greatly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try redirect all logs under `org.springframework` and see if it works? And can you post the logs that shows in the console? probably the class they are written from is a subclass of the abstract one and therefore have different class name

Comment: Hi matanper, i tried redirecting the logs from the org.springframework package but it still shows them in console logs. Can't really paste the entire log because there are some company information that i'm not allowed to show but the line that i'm trying to redirect looks like:
2019-05-02 09:29:46,321 DEBUG (AbstractBeanFactory.java:248) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean '<bean_name>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code of the top class in the hierarchy ([SimpleAliasRegistry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/SimpleAliasRegistry.java)) you'll see the initialization of the logger:

```java
/** Logger available to subclasses. */
protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
```

The `getClass()` returns the type of the concrete class in runtime. so when you see the abstract class in the log, this is the location the log was written, but the real class which gives the logger his name is some subclass.
I'd suggest you try to change the pattern to all the logs, and then it will print the name of the real logger name (which is the subclass)

Comment: Hi matanper,
Thanks to your suggestion, i was able to debug the actual sub-class at runtime that's inside of our in-house framework and extends from DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry where the logger is defined. Now when i add that class for exclussion, log messages are removed from console logs and stored in file. Even though the name of the class in file says that it's the sub-class and not the AbstractBeanFactory but this is good for me. Thanks for the help, i consider this as solved.